# Gradle Allow duplicate sourceSets

Tags: kotlin, gradle

So what im trying to do is this:

I have my main resources that should be added first

I then have dev resources that should be able to overwrite the main
resources (to replace files with eg dev configs or dev icons)

Im doing this before building my jar like this:

```
sourceSets.getByName("main") {
    resources.srcDir("src/main/resources-dev")
}
```

Sadly this fails because by default gradle doesnt want to overwrite files.

```
> Entry net/snipsniper/resources/img/systray/icon.png is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy for details.
```

So far ive tried to move the first code snippet into a copy task, where i could define a duplicateStrategy, that didnt change anything though.

I really just want the dev resources to be allowed to overwrite the base resources.